# Query value of button with current focus (together with xdotool) from the command line

Tags: linux, command-line, automation, gui, xdotools

I am using xdotool to automate some GUI usage. That works pretty well, but sometimes I want to check what button currently has focus. I need to query the value of that button. xdotool doesn't seem to support that (can only get window titles). Is there any other tool that achieves that?